# Associative-array in PHP from CSV / TXT file

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a problem with associative-array in PHP – when the source of the arrays is from a text file.

When I write something as follows:

```
$logins = array('user1' => '1234','user2' => '2345','user3' => '3456');
```

It all works as expected.

So, I tried to call those arrays from CSV file like that:

```
$file_handle = fopen("data.csv", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
  $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
  if (empty($line_of_text)) { break; }
  $logins = array($line_of_text[0] . '=>' . $line_of_text[1]); /* remove the => and seperate the logins with "," on CSV */
}
```

It didn't work.

There are a lot close related questions and answers here on SO but I did read and try to implant them without no success. Please Guide me.

Edit: `data.csv` looks like as follows.

```
user1,1234;
user2,2345;
user3,3456;
```

Comment: To help, would be useful to see an example of (1) The actual CSV you are opening, and (2) the expected / desired output.  If `data.txt` that you've shared above _is a string representation of an array_, then that will never work (note that you don't actually open `data.txt` in your code, you open `data.csv`)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: @cale_b i update the question.

Comment: @script47 i got this when i google the question before asking here but i ask it because i didn't understand the examples there (not that php expert - but want to be someday).

Comment: What do you get if you add `var_dump($line_of_text);` immediately after `$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);`?

Comment: you almost good.. just edit this line `$logins = array($line_of_text[0] . '=>' . $line_of_text[1]);` to `$logins[$line_of_text[0]] = $line_of_text[1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid those loops, conditionals, and `fopen()`/`fclose()` messiness:

```
<?php
// read the file into an array
$arr = file("data.csv", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

// split each line at the comma
array_walk($arr, function(&$v, $k){$v=explode(",", $v);});

// build an array from the data
$keys = array_column($arr, 0);
$values = array_column($arr, 1);
$logins = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think you want

```
$logins = array();
$file_handle = fopen("data.csv", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
  $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
  // At this point, $line_of_text is an array, which will look
  // something like this: {[0]=>'user1',[1]=>'1234'}
  if (empty($line_of_text)) { break; }
  $logins[$line_of_text[0]] = $line_of_text[1];
  // So the line above is equivalent to something like
  // $logins['user1'] = '1234';
}
```

This would probably also work, though I think it's not something you really want to get into

```
/* $dataFile = fopen("data.txt", "r"); */
$dataFile = file_get_contents("data.txt");
/* logins = array($dataFile); */
eval('$logins = ' . $dataFile . ';');
```